# Trying to hide HENTRY (Author Meta Data) from a Post ID

Tags: css

I am trying to hide the hentry class from a particular post ID - not sure why it doesn't work for me....

Here's the HTML

```
<header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title">Post A</h1>

    <div class="entry-meta">
            <span class="posted-on">
        <a href="XX" title="3:51 am" rel="bookmark">
          <time class="entry-date published" datetime="XXXX">June 22, 2021</time>
        </a></span>
        <span class="byline">
        <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="XXX" title="XXX">
        <span class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="XXX">[email&#160;protected]</span></a></span></span>
                <span class="comments-link"><a href="XXX">Leave a comment</a></span>
                    <!-- .entry-meta -->
     </div>

    <!-- .entry-header -->
</header>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.postid-7 .hentry .entry-meta {
    display: none;
}
```

Not sure where I am going wrong here....

Comment: The CSS is fine, by conventional WordPress CSS classes. Can't really say if it corresponds with the HTML as the posted markup only has one of three classes used in selector. Have you used dev tools to verify that your style is applying and that nothing else is overriding it?

Comment: I don't see a `.hentry` or `.postid-7` class in your HTML.

Comment: If the css selectors are correct, use `!important`

Comment: I'm with Jacob - I don't see the class selectors in the HTML you posted that correspond to ".postid-7" or ".hentry", without them your CSS declaration would be ignored for the bit of HTML you posted with ".entry-meta".